# Implementing zoom & pan in a 2 page UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to implement zooming and panning on a 2-page UIPageViewController in landscape mode. I have set a scrollview as the view of parent viewcontroller of the pageviewcontroller. This allows the pageviewcontroller to zoom, but not to pan. Is this the correct approach to implementing zooming and panning for UIPageViewcontroller or what approach should I take please?

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Comment: @amitsbajaj No, but zooming and panning a UIPageViewController is not a good user experience anyway.

Comment: That's true @RunLoop - I totally agree with that to be honest but the client wants zooming and panning on the UIPageViewController - :( so I have zooming (pinch) and panning working.. sure it doesn't look amazing, but it works, but now I'm struggling with 1) not allowing to zoom OUT and 2) getting back to the original size. I just can't figure this out and I'm so stuck! I'm desperate for any assistance with this